# Activeadmin custom action not respecting http verb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I'm trying to create a custom action to treat some information before update my model.
I have two actions for **Edit** action (one for get verb and other for post).

I'm following activeadmin docs and below is what I already tried:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Cliente do
  permit_params :nome, :caminho_imagem
  actions :all

  collection_action :edit, method: :post do
    byebug
  end     
end
```

---

```
ActiveAdmin.register Cliente do
  permit_params :nome, :caminho_imagem
  actions :all

  member_action :edit, method: :post do
    byebug
  end
end
```

---

```
ActiveAdmin.register Cliente do
  permit_params :nome, :caminho_imagem
  actions :all

  member_action :edit, method: [:post] do
    byebug
  end
end
```

---

In any of examples above, when I do **GET** into edit page, byebug is fired. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can't have a two actions with the same name, the second action will overwrite the first one. Use tow different names or use that example from MilesStanfield

Answer (score 1):

ActiveAdmin [docs](http://activeadmin.info/docs/8-custom-actions.html) used this

```
if request.post?
```

in their example

```
member_action :foo, method: [:get, :post] do
  if request.post?
    resource.update_attributes! foo: params[:foo] || {}
    head :ok
  else
    render :foo
  end
end
```

I think you may need to do the same.

Comment: Yes, but ActiveAdmin is using this because he's accepting the both verbs. I want create the custom action only for post.